# while loop with if nested inside it

Tags: java

this question might be simple for many of you but im stuck in it:/
this if condition works without while around it, but when i put while i get nothing in log

this REresponse is a response coming from server with a particular id that client sent to it plus a T or F as result to make sure the only client recieves it is the one who sent it

```
 boolean recieved = false

 String REresponse = (String) sInput.readObject();

 while(recieved=false)
 {

if (REresponse.equals("('T','"+newRID+"')")){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"you made it");

    recieved = true;
    }else if (REresponse.equals("('F','"+newRID+"')")){
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"you failed");

    recieved=true;
    }else{
        Log.i(LOGTAG,REresponse);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"some thing is wrong");
```

also i tried to use  case condition but it does accpet this

Comment: You mean `while(recieved==false)`? coz `(recieved=false)` will always be true.

Comment: Typo - should be while(recieved==false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the condition should be

```
while (received == false){
//...
}
```

if you write received = false you make an assignment, the boolean operator is ==

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning rather than equality in condition for `while`. You need to do as in  follows.

```
while(received == false)
```

Answer (score 1):

recieved = false. This always results in false so you never go into the loop when